# Plotting high frequency sinusoid with sympy produces distorted plot

Tags: python, plot, jupyter, sympy

I am building a lesson on radio modulation mathematics in a Jupyter notebook. I want to produce a graph showing the flat envelope of a simple sinusoid so I can compare it to the envelope of the product of two sinusoids.

I am representing my sinusoid as a sympy expression, albeit with a rather high frequency. When I plot it, the resulting graph is heavily distorted.

```
from sympy import *
%matplotlib inline

t = symbols('t')
f_carrier = 10000

carrier = cos(2*pi*f_carrier * t)
plot(carrier, (t, -0.001, 0.001))
```

[image: Sympy plot with strange distortion]

Making the domain tighter (-0.0005 to 0.0005) produces less distortion, but still some:
[image: Same function plotted on smaller domain]

Lower frequencies (with proportional domains), become progressively less distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for [`plot`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.plot) following the documentation, you should set the `adaptive` argument to False to allow custom number of points and set `nb_of_points` parameter of plot to a high number to increase its smoothness. (typically 10 points per cycle)

```py
from sympy import *
%matplotlib inline

t = symbols('t')
f_carrier = 10000

carrier = cos(2*pi*f_carrier * t)
plot(carrier, (t, -0.001, 0.001),adaptive = False,nb_of_points =1000)
```

[image]